# How to leave only e.g. TOP 100 records in ALL TABLES in database (SQL SERVER 2005)

Tags: database, sql

I'm having a huge database over 100GBs and I need to burn an application (for demonstration purposes) on CD or DVD which uses this huge database... is there a way how to leave for example only first 100 records IN ALL TABLES ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Create copy of database and copy necessary data to it using constructions like:

exec sp_MSforeachtable 'SELECT TOP 100 * INTO [*newdb*].[?] FROM [*olddb*].[?]';

Comment: Thanks! Ok, this is possible solution. But the fact is, that I don't know every table I need. It is very complex database and I'm using many views, which are bound to many "things" I don't know. And it's not possible to "copy" every table using TOP 100 because there are thousands of tables in this db. So there is nothing what I can do to copy the db as it is but only with some data?

Answer (score 0):

I sometimes have to do something similar, usually when I take a production database into dev or test.

In most cases, I try to identify if there is a few tables that take up almost all of the space - that is usually the case.

Run this script:

```
DECLARE @table_name VARCHAR(500)
DECLARE @schema_name VARCHAR(500)
DECLARE @tab1 TABLE(
tablename VARCHAR (500) collate database_default
,schemaname VARCHAR(500) collate database_default
)
CREATE TABLE #temp_Table (
tablename sysname
,row_count BIGINT
,reserved VARCHAR(50) collate database_default
,data VARCHAR(50) collate database_default
,index_size VARCHAR(50) collate database_default
,unused VARCHAR(50) collate database_default
)
INSERT INTO @tab1
SELECT Table_Name, Table_Schema
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
DECLARE c1 CURSOR FOR
SELECT Table_Schema + '.' + Table_Name
FROM information_schema.tables t1
WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
OPEN c1
FETCH NEXT FROM c1 INTO @table_name
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
SET @table_name = REPLACE(@table_name, '[','');
SET @table_name = REPLACE(@table_name, ']','');
--make sure the object exists before calling sp_spaceused
IF EXISTS(SELECT id FROM sysobjects WHERE id = OBJECT_ID(@table_name))
BEGIN
INSERT INTO #temp_Table EXEC sp_spaceused @table_name, false;
END
FETCH NEXT FROM c1 INTO @table_name
END
CLOSE c1
DEALLOCATE c1
SELECT t1.*
,t2.schemaname
FROM #temp_Table t1
INNER JOIN @tab1 t2 ON (t1.tablename = t2.tablename )
ORDER BY schemaname,t1.tablename;
DROP TABLE #temp_Table
```

I did not write it myself, but have it in a textfile, and I ashamed I no longer remember what source to credit... You can do the same thing in Management Studio btw (add a "Size" column to details view).

Now you know what tables take up the most space, and can deal with them indivdually.

EDIT: Found source: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/database/determine-size-of-a-table-in-sql-server/